# Get MAC address in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mac-address

Is it possible to get the client's MAC address from a Silverlight app?  It would be ideal if the solution works OOB too.

Comment: Which Code Behind Language? C# oder VB.NET?

Comment: C# would be great but either will work.

Comment: Which MAC address? What if they have more than one NIC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get the clients' MAC address in Silverlight 2 or Silverlight 3.

There's no p/invoke, trusted code, or BCL surface area for this.

Comment: So there's no way to get the MAC from inside the browser?  Not even a DOM hack or workaround?

Comment: Silverlight definitely isn't the key here, but if you have an existing hack - getting it through an installed ActiveX control or plugin, having the server somehow inject it into the page, etc., then Silverlight can read it using the HTML interoperability feature.

But be clear that there isn't a ManagementClass or any built-in functionality for this :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can get Mac Address using Java Applet or by opening the clients router status page in an iframe if java is not installed, for example with Belkin routers its http://192.168.2.1/status.stm. There are several fraud detection systems that do this for you if you are lazy and dont feel like coding it up yourself.

Comment: How is possible to detect the router (e.g if whether is Belkin or any other ) ?

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://www.thewayithink.co.uk/post/Mac-Address-in-Silverlight-4.html) you can get MAC Address in silverlight 4, using c#.