# .Net Active-X on HTML page: Can't get MAC address

Tags: .net, security, activex

I try to get mac address from active-x that is placed onto HTML web page

```
 [PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
 public string GetMacAddress()
 {
     var nic = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up);
     return nic == null ? null : nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
 }
```

But this code fails with error:

`System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0...`

Meanwhile code works great for desktop applications.

I guess there are some limitations with .net active-x usage.

How can I avoid that? Can I get unique and stable workstation ID from active-x any other way ?

Comment: I can't see where you're using ActiveX..? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces.aspx is a part of the .NET framework

Comment: Could you paste the full exception and not just the truncated first part of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found several similar issues with silverlight: 
[Get MAC address in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201351/get-mac-address-in-silverlight)

It looks there is no way to get mac address due to .net security settings except we do the following:

1. Add Active-X Host site to "Trusted"
2. Call on client machine:
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -machine
   -quiet -addgroup Trusted_Zone -site acitve-x-host-site FullTrust -name
   SecutityException -description "..."

Finally I decided to rewrite Active-X to C++\ATL one.